# Request to Reopen Question

Tags: discussion

I believe that I have fixed my question and that it deserves to be reopened. Could a mod please reopen this question?

[Duplicity Vs. Singularity of Mammals Organs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/duplicity-vs-singularity-of-mammals-organs/20619#20619)

Comment: The problem with these types of evolutionary questions is that there often isn't a reason why. It's conceivable that this is just how embryonic development evolved. Cardiogenic mesoderm, for example, initially develops bilaterally and is then brought together by embryonic folding. This same mesoderm then induces liver formation from the gut endoderm, which is why there is only one liver. However, some overarching purpose for why it evolved this way either doesn't exist or is likely unknown.

Comment: Often there is at least speculation on the part of evolutionary biologists explaining such discrepancies as described above.

Comment: While possibly interesting, this site tries to avoid speculation. That said, it is entirely possible that a valid theory actually exists for this phenomenon. My point (though I should mention that I'm not an evolutionary biologist) was that there doesn't have to be a reason. It's conceivable that an organism with two livers could exist, but that's just not the way it evolved.

Comment: @canadianer I am interested in whether such a theory exists in the evolutionary biology field.